# Can't access the object within the GraphNode

Tags: java

I have a graph that contains objects of type `GraphNodes`. These nodes contain an object `City` that has properties if It's infected or not. I want to loop through all the nodes and check if a city is infected or not. I have a generic method `getInfo` which returns an object of type `E` in my case `City`. But when i try to chain another method or to get property i can't see them as if they are not available. All the classes in the code are from college so i can't add/remove methods. I've tried with `foreach` but I still can't get the methods.

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.LinkedList;

class City {

    String osnovna_granka;
    boolean zarazen;

    City(String osnovna_granka, boolean zarazen) {
        this.osnovna_granka = osnovna_granka;
        this.zarazen = zarazen;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (zarazen == true) {
            return osnovna_granka + " zarazen";
        } else {
            return osnovna_granka + " nezarazen";
        }
    }
}

class Graph {

    int num_nodes;
    GraphNode<City> adjList[];


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Graph(int num_nodes) {
        this.num_nodes = num_nodes;
        adjList = (GraphNode<City>[]) new GraphNode[num_nodes];
    }

    int adjacent(int x, int y) {
        // proveruva dali ima vrska od jazelot so
        // indeks x do jazelot so indeks y
        return (adjList[x].containsNeighbor(adjList[y])) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    void addEdge(int x, int y) {
        // dodava vrska od jazelot so indeks x do jazelot so indeks y
        if (!adjList[x].containsNeighbor(adjList[y])) {
            adjList[x].addNeighbor(adjList[y]);
        }
    }

    void deleteEdge(int x, int y) {
        adjList[x].removeNeighbor(adjList[y]);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String ret = new String();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.num_nodes; i++) {
            ret += i + ": " + adjList[i] + "\n";
        }
        return ret;
    }
}

class GraphNode<E> {

    private int index;//index (reden broj) na temeto vo grafot
    private E info;
    private LinkedList<GraphNode<E>> neighbors;

    public GraphNode(int index, E info) {
        this.index = index;
        this.info = info;
        neighbors = new LinkedList<GraphNode<E>>();
    }

    boolean containsNeighbor(GraphNode<E> o) {
        return neighbors.contains(o);
    }

    void addNeighbor(GraphNode<E> o) {
        neighbors.add(o);
    }

    void removeNeighbor(GraphNode<E> o) {
        if (neighbors.contains(o)) {
            neighbors.remove(o);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String ret = "INFO:" + info + " SOSEDI:";
        for (int i = 0; i < neighbors.size(); i++) {
            ret += neighbors.get(i).info + " ";
        }
        return ret;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        GraphNode<E> pom = (GraphNode<E>) obj;
        return (pom.info.equals(this.info));
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public E getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(E info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public LinkedList<GraphNode<E>> getNeighbors() {
        return neighbors;
    }

    public void setNeighbors(LinkedList<GraphNode<E>> neighbors) {
        this.neighbors = neighbors;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int i, j, k;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        Graph g = new Graph(N);

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            st.nextToken();
            String osnovna_granka = st.nextToken();
            String str_zarazen = st.nextToken();
            if (str_zarazen.equals("zarazen")) {
                g.adjList[i] = new GraphNode(i, new City(osnovna_granka, true));
            } else {
                g.adjList[i] = new GraphNode(i, new City(osnovna_granka, false));
            }

        }

        int M = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            int a = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            g.addEdge(a, b);
            g.addEdge(b, a);
        }

        br.close();
        Stack<GraphNode> stack = new Stack<>();
        int counter = 0;
        // vasiot kod ovde;
        for(GraphNode gn: g.adjList) {
            gn.getInfo().// Here the properties of City should show up
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphNode is a generic type and you have not specified the type, the IDE cannot infer the type so no methods can be suggested. in the for loop you need to specify the type of the GraphNode.

```
for(GraphNode<City> gn: g.adjList)
```